# Tui chart dependency missing?

Tags: javascript, charts, tui

I tried to create a basic example with Tui chart but there seems to be a missing dependency. Is that really the problem, and if so, which dependency?

I've included the following libraries:

https://uicdn.toast.com/tui.chart/latest/tui-chart.min.css

https://uicdn.toast.com/tui.chart/latest/tui-chart.min.js

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.2.7/raphael.js

```
var container = document.getElementById('chart-area');
var data = {
    categories: [
        'Monday (2 Apr)', 
        'Tuesday (3 Apr)', 
        'Wednesday (4 Apr)', 
        'Thursday (5 Apr)', 
        'Friday (6 Apr)', 
        'Saturday (7 Apr)', 
        'Sunday (8 Apr)'
    ],
    series: [
        {
            name: 'Activity',
            data: [8, 8.5, 7.8, 6.5, 8, 0, 0]
        }
    ]
};
var options = {
    chart: {
        width: 1160,
        height: 650,
        title: 'Activities',
        format: function(value, chartType, areaType, valuetype, legendName) {
            var formattedValue = value + "h"; 
            return formattedValue;
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: 'Hours'
    },
    xAxis: {
        title: 'Days'
    },
    legend: {
        // hide the legend 
        visible: false
    },
    series: {
        // always show the value on top of each column 
        showLabel: true     
    }
};
var theme = {
    series: {
        colors: [
            '#83b14e', '#458a3f', '#295ba0', '#2a4175', '#289399',
            '#289399', '#617178', '#8a9a9a', '#516f7d', '#dddddd'
        ]
    }
};

tui.chart.columnChart(container, data, options);
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/JustM/eranq462/

Tui chart: https://github.com/nhnent/tui.chart

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found the missing dependency, it was tui-chart-code-snippets.

Comment: can you edit your answer with a full working sample? I always get tui-chart.min.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: (0 , s.default) is not a function. Then I can upvote!